# Удаление элемента с определённой позиции

Tags: jquery, dom

Добрый день.
Удаляю элемент с помощью функции:

```
function dels() {
   $('.del:last').remove();
};
```

Соответственно, удаляется последний элемент с class=del. Если хочу удалить первый, то del:first. А можно как-то указать порядковый номер элемента? Например, del:9 удалит девятый элемент с классом del... Есть что-то подобное? Или имеет смысл присваивать каждому элементу уникальный id и удалять уже по id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Девятый** элемент лучше удалить следующими способами:

```
 $('.del').eq(8).remove();
 $('.del').get(8).remove();
 $('.del')[8].remove();
```

Comment: Спасибо! А не подскажите ссылочку, где можно почитать на данную тему?

Comment: Третий способ нерабочий, вы получаете не объект jQuery, а DOM объект. remove() вроде как со списками только работает.

Comment: Ссылочки: http://jquery-docs.ru/core/eq/ , http://api.jquery.com/get/

Третий способ рабочий, я проверял. Метод get() тоже возвращает DOM объект, но это не мешает этот объект потом удалить.

Comment: @Genson http://jsfiddle.net/H5ZQp/1/

Comment: @lampa, в вашем примере у меня всё работает. Удалилось 3 элемента.

Answer (score 6):

```
$('.del:eq(9)').remove();
```

или

```
$('.del').eq(9).remove();
```

или

```
$('.del').get(9).remove();
```

или

```
$('.del')[9].remove();
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @M03G, если вам дали исчерпывающий верный ответ - то элементарной вежливостью было бы отметить его как правильный.